# setSslMode() doesn't work for PGConnectionPoolDataSource

Tags: postgresql, ssl, database-connection, datasource, connection-pooling

I am trying to set up connection pooling using PGConnectionPoolDataSource, but am unable to call `setSslMode()`, with the `error: cannot find symbol`.

According to the docs, this method should be inherited from `org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource`: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGConnectionPoolDataSource.html.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to get around this, or why this is?

Comment: This should work fine. Can you share a piece of code that shows the problem? Did you call the method with a `string` argument?

Comment: I ended up using `import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;` instead of PGConnectionPoolDataSource, and got it working with that. But FWIW, this was my code: 

      ```PGConnectionPoolDataSource source = new 
        PGConnectionPoolDataSource();
        source.setServerName("server-name");
        source.setDatabaseName("databasename");
        source.setPortNumber(5432);
        source.setUser(username);
        source.setPassword(password);
        source.setInitialConnections(50);
        source.setMaxConnections(1000);
        source.setSslMode("require");```
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet of code that shows how it works:

```java
org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource ds =
    new org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource();
ds.setSslMode("disable");
ds.setServerName("127.0.0.1");
ds.setPortNumber(5432);
ds.setDatabaseName("test");
ds.setUser("laurenz");
ds.setPassword("myverysecretpassword");
java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
conn.close();
```